# Custom Discord.py bot commands

Tags: python, eval, discord.py

Hey ya all :D im  trying to Figure out how to make custom command like Admins can type

```
!addcmd @bot_command
async def testcmd()
     print("Test")
```

The output should be the Print if someone types !testcmd the command should get saved in a json file named
commands or smth but i dont know how to start so please help me

Comment: `but i dont know how to start so please help me` maybe look up examples, tutorials, the source code of other bots, that kind of thing first, then come back if there's a specific issue.

Comment: Do you know something on youtube or maybe on Github? if so please share it with me :D

Comment: Have you ever looked the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and [`discord.py references`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)?

Comment: @LeQuit According to the [help/on-topic], `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: Here are the official [discord.py examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples) as well

Comment: I dont mean it like this... i want give my admins the ability to create commands or function via a command and the command should get saved in a txt or smth like this